# I am integrating CarPlay with an iOS app, but it gets crashed when I make an api request and other cases

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, carplay

I am integrating CarPlay into an iOS app, for `Quick food ordering`, but when I make an API request, and it returns success, the app gets crashed, as well when there's a loader presented in the iOS app itself.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CPTemplateApplicationScene
> windows]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x172371180'
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116f348a8 __exceptionPreprocess + 172  1   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x000000010a8c809c objc_exception_throw + 56  2   CoreFoundation
> 0x0000000116f496f8 +[NSObject(NSObject)
> instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0  3   UIKitCore
> 0x000000012d8ef3d4 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 232     4
> CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116f389f8
> ***forwarding*** + 1280   5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116f3ad1c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92   6   Intercom
> 0x000000010bbb424c IntercomSDK_saveViewHierarchy + 474756     7
> Intercom                            0x000000010bbb41c8
> IntercomSDK_saveViewHierarchy + 474624    8   Intercom
> 0x000000010bbb0fac IntercomSDK_saveViewHierarchy + 461796     9
> Intercom                            0x000000010bbb0f28
> IntercomSDK_saveViewHierarchy + 461664    10  Intercom
> 0x000000010bb936dc IntercomSDK_saveViewHierarchy + 340756     11
> Intercom                            0x000000010bb93650
> IntercomSDK_saveViewHierarchy + 340616    12  CoreFoundation
> 0x0000000116e6503c
> **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 140  13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116e64f60
> ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 84  14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116e64450 _CFXRegistrationPost + 404   15  CoreFoundation
> 0x0000000116e63e2c _CFXNotificationPost + 688     16  Foundation
> 0x00000001100fc0c0 -[NSNotificationCenter
> postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 88   17  UIKitCore
> 0x000000012cf7a08c -[_UISceneLifecycleMonitor willEnterForeground] +
> 240   18  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cf7ab0c
> __111-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneLifecycleMonitor transitionToTargetState:fromState:withTransitionContext:preparations:]_block_invoke_5
>
> - 120     19  UIKitCore                           0x000000012d49279c _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 96   20  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cf7a9d0 __111-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneLifecycleMonitor
>   transitionToTargetState:fromState:withTransitionContext:preparations:]_block_invoke_4
> - 128     21  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cf8b1dc ___UISceneLifecycleSettingsUpdateBlockWithCanvasAndTransitionContext_block_invoke_2
> - 288     22  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cf7a74c -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneLifecycleMonitor transitionToTargetState:fromState:withTransitionContext:preparations:]
> - 528     23  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cf8af9c ___UISceneLifecycleSettingsUpdateBlockWithCanvasAndTransitionContext_block_invoke
> - 276     24  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cf8c5d8 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_blo   25
>   UIKitCore                           0x000000012d395170
>   +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 656
>   26  UIKitCore                           0x000000012d4a8950
>   _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion
> - 196     27  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cf8c304 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]
> - 288     28  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cdee1c4 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.198
> - 608     29  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cdecf8c -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 232     30  UIKitCore                           0x000000012cdede48
>   -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 220    31  UIKitCore                           0x000000012d3bca3c
>   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 308  32  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011c7953b8
>   -[FBSScene updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:] +
>   560   33  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011c7be444
>   __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2
> - 124     34  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011c7a0bb4 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 160  35  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011c7be390
>   __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
> - 312     36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011780d93c _dispatch_client_callout + 16    37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000117811534 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 392  38
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011c7dffa0
>   **FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 44     39  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011c7dfe7c
>   -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 196     40  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011c7dffd4
>   -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24   41  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116e9569c
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24   42  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116e955e4
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 172    43  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116e94d54 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 232  44  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000116e8f43c __CFRunLoopRun + 768   45  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000116e8ed28 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572     46  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000011c2d7bc0 GSEventRunModal + 160  47  UIKitCore
>   0x000000012d8c3fdc -[UIApplication _run] + 868    48  UIKitCore
>   0x000000012d8c7c54 UIApplicationMain + 124    49  NugttahDev
>   0x000000010256f8d4 main + 64  50  dyld
>   0x000000010500d558 start_sim + 20     51  ???
>   0x00000001050ee0e0 0x0 + 4379828448   52  ???
>   0x5a1d800000000000 0x0 + 6493486975226478592 ) libc++abi: terminating
>   due to uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding this fixed the issue

```swift
extension CPTemplateApplicationScene {
    @objc var windows: UIWindow? { nil }
}
```